# How to achieve H2 DB clustering using spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot, cluster-computing, h2

My requirement is to deploy spring-boot web app in 2 servers with H2 cluster,
but not able to find any proper tutorial regarding it.
In official H2 docs:
http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#clustering
its given for separate database installation but not for embedded one.
not sure how to configure both servers to enable clustering.

Answer (score 1):

That is correct, h2 does not support clustering when running in embedded mode.
This is stated in the documentation that you linked as well:

> Clustering can only be used in the server mode (the embedded mode does not support clustering).